# How to unquote URL quoted UTF-8 strings in Python

Tags: python

```
thestring = urllib.quote(thestring.encode('utf-8'))
```

This will encode it. How to decode it?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for encode and quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
backtonormal = urllib.unquote(thestring)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you mean to decode a string from utf-8, you can first transform the string to unicode and then to any other encoding you would like (or leave it in unicode), like this

```
unicodethestring = unicode(thestring, 'utf-8')
latin1thestring = unicodethestring.encode('latin-1','ignore')
```

'ignore' meaning that if you encounter a character that is not in the latin-1 character set you ignore this character.

Comment: Isn't that just a convoluted way of doing `thestring.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1','ignore')`?